# Rselenium not working

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I'm trying to install `Rselenium` and I get this

```
Connecting to remote server"
  Error: Summary: UnknownError
Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
  class: java.net.ConnectException"
```

Code which I have tried is

```
install.packages("RSelenium")
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
checkForServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("http://www.weather.gov")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I face a connection problem. Here what I make:

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.weather.gov")
Sys.sleep(5)
```

I leave `remoteDriver()` which is the Firefox. However sometimes when I run the code I receive a connection problem. As a workaround I open the firefox on my own and after that I run the code and the code runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this in the past (see [here](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/54)). It has to do with opening the server, if you click manually on the server file (something like `selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar`), then run your code again, it should work.